# Firebase security rules calulate sum of a list

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a map like this in Firestore:

```
ratings:{
    id1:{value:5,...rest of map}
    id2:{value:3,...rest of map}
}
```

How could i calculate the **sum of values** (5+3=8) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no loop operations in the security rules programming model, as those wouldn't scale. So if you want to write a rule against the sum of the ratings, you'll have to store that sum as an explicit value in the document.